# Add a threshold filter to the Logback <configuration debug="true"> output?

Tags: java, logback

Any idea how to set a threshold filter on Logback itself's debug messages?

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] [%logger{0}] [%M:%L] - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    ...

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_SLACK_LOGS" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The above yields verbose debugging output:

```
16:05:16,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
16:05:16,480 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-test.xml] at [file:/W:/JavaProjects/logback-slack-appender/target/test-classes/logback-test.xml]
16:05:16,697 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
16:05:16,703 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
...
6:05:16,825 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@2d901eb0 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
16:05:17.696 INFO  [main] [SlackAppenderTest] [simulateAPITrouble:19] - This will fail to post to Slack
16:05:18.256 |-ERROR in com.github.maricn.logback.SlackAppender[SLACK_LOGS] - Slack POST request failed: 404 no_team
```

How to limit the debugging output to, say, just the Logback core errors? For instance:

```
16:05:17.696 INFO  [main] [SlackAppenderTest] [simulateAPITrouble:19] - This will fail to post to Slack
16:05:18.256 |-ERROR in com.github.maricn.logback.SlackAppender[SLACK_LOGS] - Slack POST request failed: 404 no_team
```

The reason is because I want to capture the output of various `addError()` calls in other people's appenders (**ideally** to a file appender), but I do not want all the verbose information on app startup.

Answer (score 0):

This looked promising, but there are no settings to control the granularity of the console messages.

```
<configuration debug="false">
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnErrorConsoleStatusListener" />
    ...
```

Instead, I created a custom proof-of-concept status listener:

```
import ch.qos.logback.core.status.Status;
import ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusListener;

public class ErrorStatusListener implements StatusListener
{
    @Override
    public void addStatusEvent( Status status )
    {
        if ( status.getLevel() >= Status.WARN )
            System.out.println( status.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Now I can control the error messages as well, and feed them back into the Logback pipeline to be picked up by a file appender.

```
17:40:32.336 INFO  [main] [SlackAppenderTest] [simulateAPITrouble:21] - This will fail to post to Slack
Slack POST request failed: 404, no_team
```